# Update_Attribute fails for Polymorphic Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my quiz game, I want to make a polymorphic association. I have a model with information about games called `Quiz`. This includes a column for `game_start`, where a `datetime` is stored and lets me do some key things like remove the game after it has started.

Users can register for games, and their sign-up is recorded in a separate model called `Reservation`. I now need the `Quiz` model to update the `Reservation` model with `game_start` info, so polymorphic seemed like the way to go.

However, I am getting an error in the console when I try to test. I am running:

```
 q = Quiz.last.game_start
   // I want to add a record in Reservation for a game_start, so I use .create here
 r = Reservation.create(game_start: 'Fri, 26 Feb 2016 13:26:00 UTC +00:00')
   // Now I want q to use the polymorphic association to update r as a test 
 q.update_attribute(:quiz_content, r)
```

This is returning an error in the console:

```
 undefined method `update_attribute' for Thu, 25 Feb 2016 15:26:00 UTC +00:00:Time
```

I also tried using `update_column` and `update_attributes` just to confirm, and I am seeing the same method error for both.

So assuming the problem is in how I set up the association, here are the two models.

**Quiz**

```
 class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quiz_content, polymorphic: true
 end
```

**Reservation**

```
 class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :quizzes, as: :quiz_content
 end
```

Other obvious stuff. I have run `rake db:migrate` and restarted the console to be sure, as well as the server. Still the same method error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`update_attribute` is a method defined for an Active Record model.

In the example q is set to what the `Quiz.last.game_start` is, which is a timestamp, and update_attribute is being called on a timestamp variable.

Actually the Quiz model is suppose to contain an id of Reservation and its type. Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Also Polymorphic associations should be used when multiple models are required to have the same kind of association. For example in StackOverflow, questions and answers have comments, and comments will have a polymorphic association with questions and answers.

If you simply want to update two models with the same time, its better to do it in the controller than go for polymorphic associations

Comment: EDIT - Just hit me that I need to change `quiz_content` to direct to the attribute. That makes sense now. ORIGINAL: Ok. When I run it that way, it solves the method error but tells me `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `quiz_content_id'. The column I am trying to update in `Reservation` is called `game_start` as well. Is the proper way to write the attribute in the `Reservation` table by having the column end in `_id` or can I customize?

Comment: Thank you for the update. So in light of that, you seem to suggest a polymorphic association is not the correct relationship here. Is there another way that I can apply a specific value from one column and apply it to the identical category of another table, for instance?

Comment: yes, also rather than querying the table, you can simply populate both column together. If you do go with polymorphic associations, you don't need to add it in both places. You can simply access `game_start` by calling `r.quiz.first.game_start`